# Помощь по форме Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, input, button

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как задать адаптивную ширину инпутам с таким отступом слева, а так же разместить кнопку по центру?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как например. Инпутам задайте ширину в 100% и `dispaly: block;` + самой форме задайте необходимые вн. отступы.

```css
form {
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

input,
textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}

input[type="submit"]{
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  <input type="text" name="text" id="text">
  <textarea name="msg" id="msg">
    
  </textarea>
  
  <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

Вот, кстати, bootstrap форма:

```css
form {
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <h2>Bootstrap form</h2>
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-center">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, я практически так и сделал, инпутам дал margin: 30px auto и width 70%, ну и display: block